# Check if a player wins in a tic tac toe game

Tags: arrays, haskell, tic-tac-toe

As a Haskell beginner, I have programmed a tic tac toe game. In first version of the game, I used 9 tuple to represent game board. I used to check winning conditions like this;

```
checkWinner :: Board -> Maybe Player
checkWinner (X,X,X,_,_,_,_,_,_) = Just Player1
checkWinner (_,_,_,X,X,X,_,_,_) = Just Player1
... same thing continues
```

Now I am trying to change my code to use arrays instead, but I can't figure out how to check for winning conditions. Lack of loops in haskell makes it hard for me to formulate an algorithm for this.

Here is my current code;

```
import Data.Array

data Tile   = EmptyTile | X | O
data Player = Player1 | Player2

showTile :: Tile -> String
showTile EmptyTile = " "
showTile X         = "X"
showTile O         = "O"

type Board = Array (Int,Int) Tile

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = array ((1,1),(3,3)) [((x,y), EmptyTile) | x <- [1,2,3], y <- [1,2,3]]

put :: Board -> Tile -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Board
put b t x y = case b!(x,y) of
                EmptyTile -> Just (b // [((x,y), t)])
                _         -> Nothing

p1wins, p2wins :: Board -> Bool
p1wins b = tileWins b X
p2wins b = tileWins b O

-- will be called with a board and either x or o
-- and it will tell whether that tile wins
tileWins :: Board -> Tile -> Bool
tileWins b t =
```

How can I implement `tileWins` function in haskell?

Comment: What should `tileWins` do, exactly? What is its type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data Tile   = EmptyTile | X | O deriving Eq

tileWins :: Board -> Tile -> Bool
tileWins b t = 
   any (\row -> all (\col -> b!(row,col) == t) [1..3]) [1..3] ||
   any (\col -> all (\row -> b!(row,col) == t) [1..3]) [1..3] ||
   all (\rc -> b!(rc,rc) == t) [1..3] ||
   all (\rc -> b!(rc,4-rc) == t) [1..3]
```

Explanation: for `t` to win one of the following must apply

- there must exist a `row` such that in all `col`umn positions we find `t`
- there must exist a `col`umn such that in all `row` positions we find `t`
- in the main diagonal we find three `t`s
- in the other diagonal we find three `t`s

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do same thing as you did for tuples, you would do:

```
if ((b ! 0 ! 0) == t
    && (b ! 0 ! 1) == t
    && (b ! 0 ! 2) == t)
   || ((b ! 1 ! 0) == t
    && (b ! 1 ! 1) == t
    ...
```

You could save few lines by using list of list of winning indices and process that.

Also, as @chi noted (my guess), `tileWins`, `p1wins` and `p2wins` should probably return a `Bool`.